# Frama-c to generate a graph object instead of dot files

Tags: graph, frama-c

I am trying to find if two programs are gamma-isomorphic or not for which I am taking the help of Jgrapht library. Now, I have to generate program dependence graphs of the programs and capture it as a graph object. Using frama-c we can generate pdgs. I used `frama-c -pdg -pdg-dot graph -pdg-print program.c` to generate pdg of the program and the output is a dot format. I have to parse the dot format to get the graph. Instead of this, will I be able to get hold of graph data structure like a graph object instead of dot file.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you should be able to extract the information you want with the functions exported in the `Db.Pdg` module of Frama-C. In particular,
`Db.Pdg.iter_nodes` allows you to iter over *all* nodes (for *all* functions) generated by the Pdg, and the `Db.Pdg.direct_*dpds` family of functions will get you the list of direct children of a given node, either all of them or only of a given kind. More information is available in the `db.mli` file inside Frama-C's sources.

That said, I have to ask you why you'd want to do that. As far as my search engine can tell me, `JGraphT` is a Java library, and last time I checked, OCaml/Java bindings weren't exactly painless to implement, if at all possible. Furthermore, it seems to me that the class `DOTImporter` of `JGraphT` should allow you to use more or less directly the output of pdg.